# window.addEventListener testing with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I have a question after searching for alot of hours but I'm unable to find a solution.

**service in AngularJS:**

```
public webViewMessage = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private windowService: WindowService) {
 const wndw = this.windowService.getWindow();
 wndw?.chrome?.webview?.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  this.webViewMessage.next(event.data);
 });
}
```

it is using WebView to receive data.

I'm trying to implement some jasmine tests for this but how do we hook into the **addEventListener** **'message'** since its being used on window how do we raise this? and is there a way to do this some-how we need to Mock the window?

Comment: In my tests, I prefer mocking `window.addEventListener`, as it's callback immediately executed regardless of event type. 

Or, if you don't want that, you can dispatch the message event by yourself just before expecting the result. But this is not the real flow of unit tests.